# C++ friend function undefined?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, implicit-conversion, friend-function

I have a struct template `A<x>` and `B<x>`, an operator overload for `A<x>+int` and a conversion from `B<x>` to `A<x>`. I want `B<x>` to be converted to `A<x>` when adding with `int`, so I used friend function declaration.

```
#include <iostream>
template<int x>
struct A{
    int a;  
};

template<int x>
struct B{
    int b=3;

    operator A<x>(){
        return {b+10};
    }
    friend int operator+(A<x> a, int b);

};


template<int x>
int operator+(A<x> a, int b){
    return a.a+b;
}


int main(){
    std::cout<<(A<12>{9}+10)<<std::endl; // This works fine
    std::cout<<(B<12>{9}+10)<<std::endl; // Error
    return 0;
}
```

Now the linker complains that 'operator+(A<12>, int)' is not defined. Could somebody tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: works perfectly for me

Comment: @HariomSingh did you *link* it?

Comment: yes even got the result 29
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Sorry I fixed the problem and was executing ..thats why was working

Comment: Gah, why is finding a dupe for this so hard?

Comment: Now I see what is wrong, but what's the solution?
(declaring friend operator template wouldn't fix it...the conversion doesn't work)

Comment: @Baum mit Augen it's not that case, so it is not exact dupe here is problem related to using foreign operator. It will not work with operator defined for other type. It may work only if defined for both or if types are related